# netlogo max and min pxcor and pycor of a patch-set

Tags: netlogo

I need to find,for a given patch-set (which is always a square), the max and min of pxcor and pycor for having a list like

```
[0 10 10 0]
```

which represent the square bounded by the points

```
(0,0), (10,0), (0,10), (10,10)
```

SO I need i mathod tath take as input a patch-set and returns a list like the one in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given a patch-set called `p-set` you can use this reporter:

```
to-report get-max-min [p-set]

   let coord []

   ask one-of p-set with-min [pxcor] [set coord lput pxcor coord]
   ask one-of p-set with-max [pxcor] [set coord lput pxcor coord]
   ask one-of p-set with-min [pycor] [set coord lput pycor coord]
   ask one-of p-set with-max [pycor] [set coord lput pycor coord]

   report coord

end
```

esample of usage:
I want to get the coordinates of patches with `pcolor = red`

```
let coord get-max-min (patches with [pcolor = red])
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I can think of is:

```
to-report get-max-min [p-set]
  let xs [pxcor] of p-set
  let ys [pycor] of p-set
  report (list min xs max xs
               min ys max ys)
end
```